# How do I split my Hbase Table(which is huge) into equal parts so that I can store it into local file system?

Tags: hadoop, export, hbase, bigdata

I have a Hbase Table of Size 53 GB that I want to store into my local file system. However I have only two drives of size 30gb each and I can't store the file completely into one drive. Could anyone please tell me how do I split and store my Hbase table into those two drives. Any suggestions or comments are deeply appreciated. There is a sense of urgency :(

Note: If anyone could suggest me whether I could split the table based on timestamp, that would be greatly appreciated. Hope to hear from you soon.

Thanks,
Gautham

Comment: 53GB is not particularly large. Certainly not huge.

Comment: ok, could you please tell me how to split the data. I am not concerned about the size at the moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to run a mapreduce job, with a full table scan and setTimerange, if want to split it by timestamp, and store the output as, for example an Avro files. Then you will be able to place those files on separate partitions.

[This](https://github.com/tmalaska/HBase-ToHDFS) can also help.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

53 gb data for the hbase is really very small. if you presplit your table, your data will also split into separate files in your file system. i assume that you  only have one node and only one region server.

Also if you have two node with one 30 gb drive and two region servers, and if you presplit your table into two, then your data is automatically splited into two if your split points is appropriate.